# deleting characters in a string using sed

Tags: linux, sed, variable

I'm trying to write a `sed` that will delete 11 numerical characters from the end of a string. here is my code...

```
fname="1a.out12345678901"

fname=$(echo "$fname"|sed 's/[0-9]{11}//')
```

however this will only set `fname` as `1a.out12345678901` how would i use `sed` to delete `12345678901` from the end of the string?

Comment: @mike It may be like this `sed 's/12345678901\n/\r/g'`

Comment: @mike would you give your sample file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash can do what without invoking external processes.

If `fname` ends with 11 numbers, this will remove them:

```
[[ $fname =~ (.*)[0-9]{11}$ ]] && fname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Notes:

1. Because this approach does not require the creation of subshells or external processes, it will be faster.  If this task is done in a loop, the speed could be important.
2. Command substitution, `$(...)`, has side-effects that you may not want.   The shell, for example, strips trailing newlines from the of command substitution.
3. This approach is not POSIX.  It requires bash.

#### Examples

This illustrates the removal of the last 11 digits:

```
$ fname="1a.out12345678901"; [[ $fname =~ (.*)[0-9]{11}$ ]] && fname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; echo "fname=$fname"
fname=1a.out
```

If fname ends with more than 11 digits, only the last 11 are removed:

```
$ fname="1a.out012345678901"; [[ $fname =~ (.*)[0-9]{11}$ ]] && fname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; echo "fname=$fname"
fname=1a.out0
```

If fname ends with less than 11 digits, none are removed:

```
$ fname="1a.out1234567890"; [[ $fname =~ (.*)[0-9]{11}$ ]] && fname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; echo "fname=$fname"
fname=1a.out1234567890
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You don't anchor to the end of the string using `$`, so this might end up deleting characters elsewhere
2. `{` is only syntactically meaningful when in ERE mode using `sed -r` where supported, otherwise you need `\{` and `\}`
3. `[0-9]` has a locale-dependent meaning, to guarantee the behaviour you desire, you should set a locale that matches your expectations (in this case, `C`)

Putting this together:

```
$ echo 1a.out12345678901 | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[0-9]\{11\}$//'
1a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several simple ways to do this. You can use head, tail or cut, no sed or regex is needed:

**By using head:**

```
fname="1a.out12345678901"
fname=$(echo "$fname"|head -c -12)
```

head -c -N, it cuts the last N-1 characters. tail can do the job too.

**By using cut:**

```
fname="1a.out12345678901"
fname=$(echo "$fname"|rev |cut -c 12-|rev)
```

rev will reverse the string

cut -c 12- means cutting the first 11 characters, and start with the 12th character.